# Copy files from remote server to local node js application folder using node-ssh

Tags: node.js, linux, ssh, scp, node-ssh

Hi I am trying to copy zip file from remote server to local node js folder . i tried like below but unable to copy file.

```
const { NodeSSH } = require('node-ssh');
const ssh = new NodeSSH();

const sshConfig = {
 host: config.host,
 port: 22,
 username: config.hostname,
 password: config.hostpassword,
};

const localZipPath = `./uploads/${zipFileName}`;
const remoteZipPath = path.posix.join(remoteDirectory, zipFileName);
        
const cmd = `scp -r ${remoteZipPath} ${localZipPath}`;
console.log(cmd);

const copyresult = await ssh.execCommand(cmd);
console.log(copyresult);
```

from the above `scp` command its copying to root directory of that remote server itself not to local node js uploads folder.Please help me how can i copy file from remote to local.

I can't user `ssh.getFile()` or `ssh.putFile()` i don't have necessary permissions to sftp connection

Comment: What permission do you not have? What happens when you run your code? Please [edit] your question to include the exact error messages that you get, if any.

Comment: @Kenster I am not getting any error messages as I explained in my question it's copying to remote directory itself not to node js directory.